# View primary key in DBeaver

Tags: dbeaver

Is there a quick way to view the primary key of a table in DBeaver? Like e.g. in the Eclipse data source explorer, where primary key rows are marked with "PK" and a special symbol.

[image: Eclipse data source explorer]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For a given table, **right click on the table name**(in Database Navigator) -> **select View Diagram.**

This will open a window like this containing a single ER Diagram for the table - 
[image]

In this diagram, the **primary keys can be seen marked as bold under the table name**, in the second partition.

To have a look at the **primary keys of all the tables**, in the Database Navigator, go to your database and then **right click on public** -> **select View diagram**. This will open the ER diagram for the whole database and the connections between the tables. Here, under each table name, the bold columns are the primary keys.

Note: A primary key can be a single key as well as a combination of multiple keys.

Comment: In my version of DBeaver (5.1.4) I can't find the menu entry "select View Diagram". However, your comment made me search for "dbeaver view diagram" which lead me to this help page: https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver/wiki/ER-Diagrams
In essence, this diagram is shown in the _rightmost tab of the Database Object Editor_, which is opened by rightclicking on the table and then clicking on **Edit Table**.
Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

As per [this github post](https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver/issues/4862), some database types (at least MySQL and PostgreSQL) show a small lightbulb to the left of the column name. This is visible in the Properties, Data and ER Diagram tabs.

Example with PostgreSQL:

[image]

Comment: In DBeaver (21.2.0), their developers no longer lock their house doors with lightbulbs and this icon has been changed into a key symbol. Not a very good one, because until I found this question and these answers (and used Windows zoom just now), I always thought it was a question mark (it's very tiny!). And it's blue, because key icons are yellow everywhere else. I learned something.