# How to list all primary keys in database?

Tags: sql, dbeaver

i'm at the very start of learning about how to code and started from SQL and Python.
I have a task: to list all primary keys in data base. How can I do it?
[Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5qdDG.png)
I used

```
 select * from public
```

But it returns with error

Comment: You ca have a look in below link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54628931/view-primary-key-in-dbeaver#:~:text=To%20have%20a%20look%20at,columns%20are%20the%20primary%20keys.

Comment: Do you need to do it programmatically for some databases or just view  them for a particular database?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  dbeave is a GUI tool, not a database.

Answer (score -1):

This the query will list all the primary keys for a SQL Server database:

```
select * from sys.objects where type = 'PK'
```

Comment: Do not post code-only answers, add an explanation to your code. And not all databases have the same system tables, so this is not a cathall solution

Comment: To be clear: this will provide a list of the primary key **constraints** in the current SQL Server database. It does **not** provide the name of the columns in those constraints, nor does it list the **values** in those columns